# Novel about kids raised with aliens that shed hands and head

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read it about 1992.
A human colony exists on a very hot planet. There are benevolent aliens that shed their head and hands as part of their life cycle.
The kids want to grow up faster so they decapitate one of their group and get sent to various prisons.
The story picks up many years later when they are adults.
More details:

- I believe the humans have to use VERY thick sunscreen on the planet.
- One of the girls becomes a sex slave to aquatic aliens.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I found it.

"Alien Influences," by Kristine Kathryn Rusch

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/372005.Alien_Influences

It turns out six children were beheaded, not one. And the aliens were called "dancers."

Comment: Perfectly alright. Please add information to indicate why this matches, and then accept your answer. ^_^